# Detect View/Page change

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Forms project which should be strict in Portrait mode and only have 2 pages which should be displayed in landscape mode. Currently I'm forcing all pages into portrait by using

```
RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

at the beginning of the MainActivity.cs. In this activity I have some MessagingCenter Subscribe methods which changes the RequestedOrientation to landscape and to portrait

```
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page>(this, "goLandscape", sender =>
        {
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
        });

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page>(this, "goPortrait", sender =>
        {
            RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
        });
```

In the OnAppearing method of the page which should be displayed in landscape mode I send the "goLandscape" message, and in the OnDisappearing I send "goPortrait".

The problems occurs when I change between pages which have different orientations. Most of the time the layout will be "shifted".

Example picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6pN2.jpg The Label and Button should be centered and the grey background should be filled to the bottom.
I also tried to Invalidate the Layout after the rotation happend but that hasn't changed anything.

I figured out that probably the MessagingCenter is the cause of the problem, so I'm looking for a different approach how to handle the orientation. 
Currently I'm trying to change the rotation before the custom renderer is drawing anything but I can't find any methods which are called before the MainActivity or the custom page renderer is drawing anything of the UI. Are there methods which I can override?

Are there any other approaches how to handle forced orientation changes without destroying the layout?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not delete and re-post the same question under a new user : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421935/xamarin-android-set-orientation-for-single-pages

Comment: Try only using the OnAppearing event only. Just add your ScreenOrientation message for each page

Comment: I've created a FixedOrientationPage to do the trick for me, creating a custom renderer to handle the Orientation property on android platform.

Comment: Not sure an app that forces a page orientation on its users will go down well. Can't you figure out a way to allow the page to suit whatever orientation the user wants?

Comment: Is [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421935/xamarin-android-set-orientation-for-single-pages) can't solve your problem ?  When you invalidate the layout after the rotation have you add a delay ?